# Frame issue in iPad pro of custom keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

custom keyboard is properly working Landscape and portrait mode in all iPhone and iPad device and simulator, when run keyboard in iPad Pro then properly work in portrait mode then i go to landscape mode in iPad pro so keyboard frame is ruined in all outer app like safari, message etc, this issue only iPad pro, so how can solve this.

this keyboard properly work portrait and landscape mode on my app like this
[image]

[image]

When i use safari or another app so landscape frame is ruined like this
[image]

[image]

this keyboard is woking proper in all device just problem in iPad pro.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you using constraints between your custom keyboard and the KeyboardViewController?

Comment: i already try to use constraint and frame both take same output. now i am using frame.

Comment: If you're using frame based layout then you'll have to update your custom keyboard's frame whenever the device changes its orientation.

Comment: yes bro. i already do it when screen is portrait mode so frame is 1366*1024 and landscape mode 1024*1366 but not get perfect layout in iPad pro.

Comment: Do you want the keyboard to only remind centered then are you also updating the view.frame.origin? Your keyboard.centerPoint and KeyboardViewController.view.centerPoint should be the same. If you want your keyboard to have to same size and origin as the KeyboardViewController.view then do keyboard.frame = KeyboardViewController.view.frame.